changing kapacitor batch query to work with influx2.7.10
since influx2 does not work with db and retention policies, instead it defines buckets, I am trying to update the following kapacitor batch query (which works with influx1) to work with influx2:
batch
                |query('SELECT last('+column+'), mean('+column+'), stddev('+column+') FROM influxdb.'+retentionPolicy+'.'+measurement)
                .period(period)
....

I have tried
FROM "one_hour/autogen".' + measurement

and
FROM one_hour.' + measurement

but none is working. I get syntax errors. The 'one_hour' is the bucket name of course. Any idea how the query should look like? Thank you in advance.
